# Is there extension or function to know bracket declaration when focued close bracket

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, emacs, ckeditor

I want to know declaration of open bracket when focused close bracket.(ex. if (...) ).

I know emacs, vscode, vim are has goto declaration function. But, they needs 1 action(type M-.(emacs),F12(vscode),%(vim)). I don't want to type some key each time. So, I want to know declaration of bracket with 0-action.

I don't care how displays in declaration(pop-up, mini buffer, status bar)

Background:
I'm in fixing legacy code. The code is too much nested with ifs and fors and whiles.
By much nested, end of code are many continus close bracket(}) like below.

```
for (var item in list){
  if (cond1) {
    ...
    while( cond2 ) {
      ...
        if (cond3) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
      }
    }
    list.append(item)
  }
}
```

I usually mistake cond2 and cond3, created bugs, don't show log messages, and spent much time.

This question was translated by google translator. so, if you couldn't recognise this, please comment.

Comment: you could just use hideshow.el to fold your code blocks

Comment: You can use one of the [rainbow parentheses](https://github.com/junegunn/rainbow_parentheses.vim/blob/master/README.md) or rainbow brackets plugins to color them differently and match colors between open and close brackets. There are multiple such plugins and for all editors, so search one that will work well for you depending on your requirements and preferences.

Comment: @filbranden didnt we have something like this on [vi.se] a while back where the asker wanted to show the whole line containing the matching paren?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I don't really recall it... Highlighting the whole line would be odd if you had multiple on the same line, or open and close on the same line too...

Comment: @filbranden Found it! https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/22216/10604 OP, if you have more vim questions, feel free to come see us at [vi.se]! I have a feeling you'll find the answers in the linked Q worthwhile

Comment: greats! thanks every one! cool plug-ins. I'll use it.

Comment: @filbranden thanks your advice, rainbow was not fit i wanted. but your comments was great pressure for me, cos my question was odd or curiously. and finally, i could know nice plug-ins.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks to tell me nice plugins. i'll try it. and, if i could, try to join in vi and vim!

Answer (score 1):

When your cursor is on a bracket, the other one is highlighted automatically if you have `:help matchparen` enabled.

When your cursor is on a bracket, you can jump to the opening one with `:help %`.

Comment: thanks to nice advice. your advice might to be able apply to other editors! when i use emacs or vscode, i'll find such setting. of course, i didn't know matchparen setting, so i can be to apply to vim when plain vim environment

Answer (score 1):

To quote [Mass](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22218/10604):

> Yes- the plugin match-up has this feature:
>   https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> Using the option
>
> ```
> let g:matchup_matchparen_offscreen = { 'method': 'popup' }
> ```
>
> There is also the ability to show the match in the statusline (the
>   default):
>
> ```
> let g:matchup_matchparen_offscreen = { 'method': 'status' }`
> ```

Comment: great! nice plug-ins! that's i wanted it! thank you very much!